# Data Time Format(Duration)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a query like i want to show the time information in custom format like(1min 06sec) from date .I have a filed Duration in database and when i am binding my data control then in item i want to display in above format(1min 06 sec),so is it possible?

Comment: What is the min and max of this duration? Does it go into hours and days and months? And how is the data stored in the db. Is it a Datetime type?

Comment: is it stored in one database column, if yes, how is it separated. Can you show us how the Duration is stored in your database ?

Comment: i have a duration column in database table and the datatype is datetime .

Comment: If it is DateTime can you give us an example of the actual data in the database field? I can't see how you are getting 1 min and 06 seconds from a DateTime field. Are you doing a date diff somewhere (SQL or C#)

Answer (score 2):

Checkout this documentation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

But, assuming you have a `DateTime` object, something like this should do the trick:

```
var test1 = DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("m'min 's'sec'");
```

Or for a `TimeSpan`:

```
var test2 = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(123).ToString("m'min 's'sec'");
```

You can easily add in hours/days/etc. depending on the exact format you want.  If your object isn't a DateTime or TimeSpan object, you will have to do something custom.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.TimeSpan` structure. It represents time interval.
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Given you DateTime variable, you could do the following:

```
  var rr = dt1.ToString("mm'min 'ss'sec'");
```

**Or if you have a TimeSpan:**

You'll need to use a TimeSpan for this. A simplistic approach is the following:

```
  var ts = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 30);
  var result = ts.Minutes.ToString() + "min " + ts.Seconds.ToString() + "sec";
```

In this example, I've set the TimeSpan variable to 2 minutes and 30 seconds.

**Or if you have two dates:**
If you have two dates you can do a diff and get the timespan and from there use the code I've shown above:

```
  var dt1 = new DateTime(2011, 01, 01, 12, 01, 00);
  var dt2 = new DateTime(2011, 01, 01, 12, 03, 30);
  var diffTimeSpan = dt2.Subtract(dt1);
  var r = diffTimeSpan.Minutes.ToString() + "min " + diffTimeSpan.Seconds.ToString() + "sec";
```

Comment: Just to clarify a bit: Timespan is (int hours, int minutes, int seconds) You can extract that information from your DateTime object

Comment: I think your literal denoter in your first example needs to be put before every letter i.e., `\\m\\i\\n` .  If you want to denote blocks as literal you have to do it like mine with `'min'` type denotion I believe.  Also your TimeSpan should use the built in .ToString() formatting like your DateTime example, it's a bit long/ugly otherwise and hard to expand.  With .ToString format you can just make the format a string const and it's real simple to change the display when needed.

Comment: @mrnye it works as it is. I've tested the code before posting it. You're correct about the TimeSpan and toString, however I provided a "simplistic" approach because I wanted the OP to understand that he can access the "parts" of a timespan. Providing a format string does not make that clear.

Comment: Yeah it works because i/n/e/c are all probably not defined in the format. But if in the future they were ever to be defined, it would break.  it's just clearer to explicity state what is literal and what is formatting.